# Multiple delimiter process in bigquery sql

Tags: sql, regex, replace, google-bigquery, regexp-replace

I need bigquery sql to process a column with outer-level delimiter ^G and inner-level delimiter space, from example if input column is
`a 11^Gb 22^Gc 33`, then we should give two output columns `a^Gb^Gc` and `11^G22^G33`. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can consider below

```
-- sample data
WITH sample_table AS (
 SELECT 'a 11^Gb 22^Gc 33' str UNION ALL
 SELECT 'a AA^Gb BB^Gc CC' str
)
-- query starts here
SELECT str,
       (SELECT AS STRUCT
               STRING_AGG(SPLIT(out, ' ')[OFFSET(0)], '^G') col1,
               STRING_AGG(SPLIT(out, ' ')[OFFSET(1)], '^G') col2
          FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(str, '^G')) out
       ).*
  FROM sample_table;

-- query result
+------------------+---------+------------+
|       str        |  col1   |    col2    |
+------------------+---------+------------+
| a 11^Gb 22^Gc 33 | a^Gb^Gc | 11^G22^G33 |
| a AA^Gb BB^Gc CC | a^Gb^Gc | AA^GBB^GCC |
+------------------+---------+------------+
```

Comment: An additional question, in my example, col1 output is a^Gb^Gc, how can I order it in desc, to get col1, in c^Gb^Ga. Thank you so much!

Comment: `STRING_AGG()` function supports `ORDER BY` clause in it, so you can try it like this.
`STRING_AGG(SPLIT(out, ' ')[OFFSET(0)], '^G' ORDER BY SPLIT(out, ' ')[OFFSET(0)] DESC) col1`.

Answer (score 1):

Another option

```
select str, 
  array_to_string(regexp_extract_all(str, r'(?:([^\s]+) [^\s]*?)(?:\^G|$)'), '^G') as col1,
  array_to_string(regexp_extract_all(str, r'(?:[^\s]+ ([^\s]*?))(?:\^G|$)'), '^G') as col2
from your_table
```

with output like

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `regex_replace()` to replace number or small letters and replace() to remove spaces

```
select replace(regexp_replace(colname, '[0-9]', ''),' ','')column1, replace(regexp_replace(colname, '[a-z]', ''),' ','')column2
```